# Exchange data between stack of classes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns

Consider we have a stack of linked classes. Pseudo-code:

```
template<class CMyLevelHigher, class CMyLevelLower>
class CMyLevel 
{
public:
    CMyLevel(CMyLevelHigher* t_higher, CMyLevelLower* t_lower)
        :   m_higher(t_higher),
            m_lower(t_lower) 
    {
        // ...
    }

    void ProcessInHigher(/* data */) 
    {
        // ...

        if (m_higher != nullptr) {
            m_higher->ProcessInHigher(/* data */);
        }

        // ...
    }

    void ProcessInLower(/* data */) 
    {
        // ...

        if (m_lower != nullptr) {
            m_lower->ProcessInLower(/* data */);
        }

        // ...
    }

private:
    CMyLevelHigher* m_higher{ nullptr };
    CMyLevelLower* m_lower{ nullptr };
}
```

Purpose of them is to process `data` and move them to lower or higher direction (class design may be incorrect, its for idea only). For example, for net protocol stack abstraction.

Parameters in `/* data */` can be of any type depending on purpose of current level.

Do you know any design patterns or programming best practices to realize this behavior?

Comment: What is the question? You already provided your design. What input to you seek here?

Comment: @SergeyA My question is how to templatize function parameters? (/*data*/)

Comment: The way to templatize the function parameter is to make it a template parameter. You are really providing answers as questions.

Comment: @SergeyA ok, may be you can give me a hint: how to templatize variable number of parameters?

Comment: Which C++ dialect? In C++11+, you use variadic templates. In pre-11 (really?) you have two options:
a. Provide a number of overloads covering the maximum number of arguments you can expect (I do not like this solution, just listing it)
b. Accept a tuple as your argument.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, C++11 or newer. Can you briefly tell about "accept a tuple as your argument", I cannot get the idea...

Comment: As I said, if you have C++11, you do not need tuple solution - you just use variadic templates. The idea behind tuple solution is to accept a tuple as your argument, and than extract your args from the tuple. Variadics a a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

In your example, both CMyLevelHigher and CMyLevelLower inherite a new base abstract class, CMyLevelBase, such that

```
template < typename ARGS >
class CMyLevelBase {
public:
    virtual void Process(const ARGS& args) = 0;
};

struct Args { /* specific parameters */ };
class CMyLevelHigher : public MyLevelBase<Args> { ... };
class CMyLevelLower  : public MyLevelBase<Args> { ... };

template < typename ARGS >
class CMyLevel {
    ...
public:
    void ProcessInHigher(const ARGS& args) { m_higher->ProcessInHigher(args); }
    void ProcessInLower (const ARGS& args) { m_lower ->ProcessInHigher(args); }
private:
    CMyLevelBase<ARGS>* m_higher{ nullptr };
    CMyLevelBase<ARGS>* m_lower { nullptr };
};
```

By using Strategy Pattern, CMyLevel becomes independent from CMyLevelHigher, CMyLevelLower and Args. Therefore this desing accomplishes ISP (Interface Segregation Principle) and DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle).